# SQL query for dataset in SSRS

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I put two parameters in a query; [A_from] and [A_to] to decide some value in table for data set.

The both of parameters allow Null/empty and the value changes by parameter as you can see below.
How can I write query for this? (Tried case statement, but doesn't work..)

```
Input)                 Output)
A_From and A_To        some Value Between A_From And A_To 
Only A_From            some value >= A_From
Only A_To              some value <= A_To
Both NULL              * (all)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since comparisons to `null` always yield `false`, you can use this:

```
select *
from my_table t
where
  (t.value >= A_From and t.value <= A_To) or
  (t.value >= A_From and A_To is null) or
  (A_From is null and t.value <= A_To) or
  (A_From is null and A_to is null)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I've just tried, but it returned nothing when I input Only A_from and also both null(supposed to return all value of t.value)

Comment: @Kitty_jp: i'm not sure what you mean by "input Only A_from and also both null". Are you referring to the value of the `value` field in the table or the parameters? If you're talking about just the parameters, that statement is contradictory. Can the `value` field also be `null`? If so, does that row match?

Comment: Sorry for my English. I meant it returns nothing when I input some value in the parameter:A_From, but input nothing to A_To. Also, it returns nothing when I gave the both parameters null value.

Comment: @Kitty_jp: I just tried it here and it works perfectly. You're likely not adapting the SQL to your table structure properly. Can you supply your table structure?

Comment: Yes, I'm referring to the value of the value field, e.g) employee code, in the table. Parameters are used to decide its range. It's okay to not input any value to the parameters. In the case, the result should be all the employee code without range specification.

Comment: @Kitty_jp: It works perfectly here. Are you sure you're referencing the params properly in the SQL? How depends on which DB you're using. Also, please give your table structure.

Comment: Humm..maybe I mistyped or something. Let me try again after sleep( now it's bfr 3 a.m here )

Comment: @Kitty_jp: the field name is `employee code` with a space?

Comment: No, actually. I meant a field that has employee code as one of example. Field name could be anything.